# Getting error in viewbag list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass queried data from controller to view and I am using ViewBag for this. But getting error while writing View code.

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace club.Models
{
    public class DetailMember
     {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

}

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ViewDetail(string id)
    {
         var db= new clubDataContext();
        int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        var list = (from m in db.M_Registarions where m.M_id == id1 select new DetailMember() { FirstName = m.M_Fname, LastName = m.M_Lname, Gender = m.M_Gender }).ToList();
        ViewBag.memberDetail = list;
```

View:

```
@model club.Models.DetailMember
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "ViewDetail";
 }
<h2>ViewDetail</h2>
@foreach (var item in (List<**DetailMember**>)ViewBag.memberDetail)
{

}
```

Here I am getting error in DetailMember List. I don't know what is wrong in this. Please help me to solve this error. 
Error: The type or namespace name 'DetailMember' could not be found

Comment: Error: The type or namespace name 'DetailMember' could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using simple foreach:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.memberDetail)
{
<span>@item.FirstName</span>
}
```